# Problem with python module?

Tags: python

Trying to use vtools on my bio-linux (v.8) on  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
I get this Error:

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/python': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007facee4ff060 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7facf20e57e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7facf20ede0a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7facf20f198c]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simuPOP/_simuPOP_muop.so(_ZNSt6locale5_Impl16_M_install_facetEPKNS_2idEPKNS_5facetE+0x142)[0x7facee159f72]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simuPOP/_simuPOP_muop.so(_ZNSt6locale5_ImplC1Em+0x1e3)[0x7facee13d983]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simuPOP/_simuPOP_muop.so(_ZNSt6locale18_S_initialize_onceEv+0x15)[0x7facee13e8f5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xea99)[0x7facf2445a99]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simuPOP/_simuPOP_muop.so(_ZNSt6locale13_S_initializeEv+0x21)[0x7facee13e941]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simuPOP/_simuPOP_muop.so(_ZNSt6localeC1Ev+0x13)[0x7facee13e983]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simuPOP/_simuPOP_muop.so(_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev+0xbc)[0x7facee1664dc]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simuPOP/_simuPOP_muop.so(+0x13b750)[0x7faceddd8750]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x104ea)[0x7facf26644ea]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x105fb)[0x7facf26645fb]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x15712)[0x7facf2669712]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x10394)[0x7facf2664394]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x14bd9)[0x7facf2668bd9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0xf09)[0x7facf1e6af09]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(+0x10394)[0x7facf2664394]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0x1571)[0x7facf1e6b571]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(dlopen+0x31)[0x7facf1e6afa1]
/usr/bin/python(_PyImport_GetDynLoadFunc+0xf3)[0x5231c3]
/usr/bin/python(_PyImport_LoadDynamicModule+0x4f)[0x522d6f]
/usr/bin/python[0x5c7175]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x68a)[0x4c468a]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x5d8f)[0x4c9d8f]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x255)[0x4c2765]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x19)[0x4c2509]
/usr/bin/python(PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+0xcb)[0x4c061b]
/usr/bin/python[0x4bd6ee]
/usr/bin/python[0x4afbad]
/usr/bin/python(PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+0x8bd)[0x4af34d]
/usr/bin/python[0x4b0f78]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x4b0cb3]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x30)[0x4ce5d0]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2ed6)[0x4c6ed6]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x255)[0x4c2765]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x19)[0x4c2509]
/usr/bin/python(PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+0xcb)[0x4c061b]
/usr/bin/python[0x4bd6ee]
/usr/bin/python[0x4be9e7]
/usr/bin/python[0x4afbad]
/usr/bin/python(PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+0x9b2)[0x4af442]
/usr/bin/python[0x4b0f78]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x4b0cb3]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x30)[0x4ce5d0]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2ed6)[0x4c6ed6]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x255)[0x4c2765]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x19)[0x4c2509]
/usr/bin/python(PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+0xcb)[0x4c061b]
/usr/bin/python[0x4bd6ee]
/usr/bin/python(PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+0x785)[0x4af215]
/usr/bin/python[0x4b0f78]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x4b0cb3]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x30)[0x4ce5d0]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2ed6)[0x4c6ed6]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x255)[0x4c2765]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x19)[0x4c2509]
/usr/bin/python(PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+0xcb)[0x4c061b]
/usr/bin/python[0x4bd6ee]
/usr/bin/python(PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+0x785)[0x4af215]
/usr/bin/python[0x4b0f78]
/usr/bin/python(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x4b0cb3]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x30)[0x4ce5d0]
```

I don't know how to solve this. It seems a python module I've installed has a bug?

How can I solve the problem?